# ¿Estoy haciendo bien mi inserción de datos en mi tabla de Access?

Tags: java, ms-access

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto sencillo para la escuela, y estoy usando Access como gestor de base de datos.

La conexión me va de maravilla. El problema viene cuando trato de insertar datos en una tabla de mi BD. Al tratar de hacerlo me manda el siguiente error:

**net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::4.0.4 usuario no tiene privilegios suficientes o objeto no encontrado: GALLETAS**

A continuación pongo la parte del código que se supone, hace la inserción en la tabla de Access.

```
public void guardar(producto x) throws SQLException {
   con = obtnerConexion();       
   Statement st = con.createStatement();       
   String q = "insert into inventario(Codigo,Descripcion,Clasificacion) values  "+"("+x.getCodigo()+
                                                                                ","+x.getDesc()+
                                                                                ","+x.getClasif()+")";
   try {
        st.executeUpdate(q);            
        con.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {            
        System.out.println(e);            
    }
}
```

Mi duda es que estoy haciendo mal con el intento de inserción. Espero haber sido claro con mi pregunta. Gracias.

Comment: Hola que tal, Dan, por lo que se ve en el error tenes problemas con los permisos de acceso a la base de datos o el objeto GALLETAS no existe. deberias poner la estructura de tu base de datos y los usuarios. No parece ser un problema de la funcion

Comment: Puede que tu sintaxis sea errónea. En los `INSERT` los valores que son cadena deben ir rodeados por comillas simples. Eso no se está haciendo en tu variable `q`
 ¿o acaso los tres valores son numéricos?

Comment: @A.Cedano no todos son valores numéricos. x.getDesc() y getClasif() son cadenas de caracteres. Podrias explicar mejor lo de que deben ir rodeados por comillas simples?

Comment: Entonces debería quedar así: `String q = "insert into inventario(Codigo,Descripcion,Clasificacion) values "+"("+x.getCodigo()+ ",'"+x.getDesc()+ "','"+x.getClasif()+"')";` para que la consulta final quede de este modo: `insert into inventario(Codigo,Descripcion,Clasificacion) values  (1,'b','c')` como puedes ver, `b` y `c` quedan rodeados por comillas simples. Aunque lo mejor en estos casos es usar consultas preparadas, pero ese es otro asunto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes tener en cuenta que en las consultas SQL, los valores que son cadena deben ir rodeados por comillas simples, produciéndose un código parecido a este:

```
insert into inventario(Codigo,Descripcion,Clasificacion) values (1,'b','c');
```

Si observas bien, tanto `b` como `c` están entre comillas simples. Cuando construyes una cadena usando variables o métodos, como es tu caso, debes tomarlo en cuenta, para agregar las comillas simples respectivas donde corresponda.

Debería quedar entonces así:

```
String q = "insert into inventario(Codigo,Descripcion,Clasificacion) values " + "(" + 
                x.getCodigo() + 
                ",'" + x.getDesc() + 
                "','" + x.getClasif() + "')";
```

### Sugerencia sobre la seguridad y el rendimiento

Este tipo de consultas que manejan datos que dependen del usuario deberían ejecutarse usando consultas preparadas, si no se usa, un usuario mal intencionado podría manipular la información y enviar consultas dañinas para la base de datos o para el sistema, es el riesgo conocido con *Inyección SQL* (sugiero que te documentes sobre el tema cuando puedas).

Tu código implementando consultas preparadas, quedaría así:

```
public void guardar(producto x) throws SQLException {
   con = obtnerConexion();       
   String q = "insert into inventario(Codigo,Descripcion,Clasificacion) values  (?, ?, ?)";
   try {
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(q);
            ps.setInt(1,x.getCodigo());
            ps.setString(2,x.getDesc());
            ps.setString(3,x.getClasif());
            ps.executeUpdate();
            con.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {            
        System.out.println(e);            
    }
}
```

Básicamente, la consulta se escribe usando marcadores (signos de `?`) por cada valor que proviene del exterior y luego esos valores se pasan aparte, usando el método adecuado, en este caso `setInt` para el primer valor, porque es numérico y `setString` para los otros valores que son cadenas. Si observas bien, en el caso de consultas preparadas los marcadores no van rodeados de nada, sirven simplemente para decir que *ahí va un valor el cual voy a pasar luego*. Los set tienen que pasarse según el orden que corresponda a cada uno, indicando a la izquierda la posición `1, 2, 3 ...` tal y como deban asignarse los datos según la el orden en que están en la consulta.

---

#### Información adicional

Ver la [documentación de Java sobre las consultas preparadas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).